PDFBox can't map correctly
This is my code now to map and show all the pages of an ebook in a JavaFx application and I know that I'm not mapping all possible things but what I'm mapping I'm not able to do the same as it is in the ebook
    public void adicionarNovaTab(Ebook ebookSelecionado) {
        try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(ebookSelecionado.getConteudo())) {
            PDPageTree pages = document.getPages();
            CustomTab customTab = new CustomTab(ebookSelecionado.getNome());

            int pageNumber = 1;
            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

            VBox vBox = new VBox();
            vBox.setSpacing(20);
            vBox.setMinWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            vBox.setMinHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            vBox.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            vBox.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            for (PDPage page : pages) {
                Pane pane = new Pane();
                Background background = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("WHITE"), null, null));
                pane.setBackground(background);
                double pageWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
                double pageHeight = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
                pane.setPrefSize(pageWidth, pageHeight);
                pane.setMinSize(pageWidth, pageHeight);
                pane.setMaxSize(pageWidth, pageHeight);

                List<TextoComCoordenadas> textoComCoordenadas = extrairTextoDaPagina(pageNumber, page, document);

                textoComCoordenadas.forEach(texto -> {
                    Text text = new Text(String.valueOf(texto.getCaractere()));
                    text.setX(texto.getX());
                    text.setY(texto.getY());

                    if (texto.getFonte() != null && texto.getFonte().getInputStream() != null) {
                        Font font = Font.loadFont(texto.getFonte().getInputStream(), texto.getFontSize());
                        text.setFont(font);
                    } else {
                        Font font = Font.font(texto.getFonte() != null && texto.getFonte().getNome() != null ? texto.getFonte().getNome() : "Arial",
                                texto.isBold() ? FontWeight.BOLD : FontWeight.NORMAL,
                                texto.isItalic() ? FontPosture.ITALIC : FontPosture.REGULAR,
                                texto.getFontSize());
                        text.setFont(font);
                    }


                    pane.getChildren().add(text);
                });
                vBox.getChildren().add(pane);
                pageNumber++;

                scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
                scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true); // Ajusta a largura do conteúdo ao ScrollPane
                scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true); // Ajusta a altura do conteúdo ao ScrollPane
                customTab.setContent(scrollPane);

                if (!tabPaneVisualizador.getTabs().contains(customTab)) {
                    tabPaneVisualizador.getTabs().add(customTab);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private List<TextoComCoordenadas> extrairTextoDaPagina(int numeroDaPagina, PDPage page, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        List<TextoComCoordenadas> textosComCoordenadas = new ArrayList<>();

        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
        Iterable<COSName> fontNames = resources.getFontNames();
        fontNames.forEach(font -> {
            try {
                PDFont pdFont = resources.getFont(font);
                String nomeFonte = pdFont.getName();
                boolean temMesmoNome = fontesDosEbooks.stream().anyMatch(fonte -> fonte.getNome().equals(nomeFonte));

                if (!temMesmoNome && pdFont.getFontDescriptor() != null && pdFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile() != null) {
                    COSInputStream cosInputStream = pdFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile().createInputStream();
                    FonteDoEbook fonte = FonteDoEbook.builder().nome(nomeFonte).inputStream(cosInputStream).build();
                    fontesDosEbooks.add(fonte);
                    System.out.println("Adicionado uma fonte: " + nomeFonte);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
            @Override
            protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
                for (int i = 0; i < textPositions.size(); i++) {
                    TextPosition textPosition = textPositions.get(i);
                    float x = textPosition.getXDirAdj();
                    float y = textPosition.getYDirAdj();
                    boolean italic = false;
                    boolean forceBold = false;
                    float fontSize = textPosition.getFontSize();
                    final String nomeDaFonte = textPositions.get(i).getFont().getName();

                    if (textPosition.getFont().getFontDescriptor() != null) {
                        italic = textPosition.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isItalic();
                        forceBold = textPosition.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isForceBold();
                        if (!italic && nomeDaFonte.toLowerCase().contains("-it")) {
                            italic = true;
                        }
                        if (!forceBold && nomeDaFonte.toLowerCase().contains("bold")) {
                            forceBold = true;
                        }
                    }

                    TextoComCoordenadas.TextoComCoordenadasBuilder textoComCoordenadasBuilder =
                            TextoComCoordenadas.builder()
                                    .caractere(text.charAt(i))
                                    .x(x)
                                    .y(y)
                                    .fontSize(fontSize)
                                    .bold(forceBold)
                                    .italic(italic);

                    Optional<FonteDoEbook> first = fontesDosEbooks.stream()
                            .filter(fonte -> fonte.getNome().equals(nomeDaFonte)).findFirst();

                    if (first.isPresent())
                        textoComCoordenadasBuilder.fonte(first.get());
                    else {
                        FonteDoEbook fonte = FonteDoEbook.builder().nome(nomeDaFonte).build();
                        fontesDosEbooks.add(fonte);
                    }

                    textosComCoordenadas.add(textoComCoordenadasBuilder.build());
                }
            }
        };
        textStripper.setStartPage(numeroDaPagina);
        textStripper.setEndPage(numeroDaPagina);
        textStripper.getText(document);

        return textosComCoordenadas;
    }

Saying again: I'm not talking about the things that I'm not mapping by now like colors, underscores
I think the real problem is the spacing beetween the words and the font properly, and I don't know why, because I'm using this foreach to get all the fonts from the PDF which are added to PDF because isn't a standard font:
        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
        Iterable<COSName> fontNames = resources.getFontNames();
        fontNames.forEach(font -> {
            try {
                PDFont pdFont = resources.getFont(font);
                String nomeFonte = pdFont.getName();
                boolean temMesmoNome = fontesDosEbooks.stream().anyMatch(fonte -> fonte.getNome().equals(nomeFonte));

                if (!temMesmoNome && pdFont.getFontDescriptor() != null && pdFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile() != null) {
                    COSInputStream cosInputStream = pdFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile().createInputStream();
                    FonteDoEbook fonte = FonteDoEbook.builder().nome(nomeFonte).inputStream(cosInputStream).build();
                    fontesDosEbooks.add(fonte);
                    System.out.println("Adicionado uma fonte: " + nomeFonte);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

package br.com.danielschiavo.livrariavirtual.util;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.InputStream;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "nome")
public class FonteDoEbook {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    private String nome;
}

package br.com.danielschiavo.livrariavirtual.util;

import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class TextoComCoordenadas {

    private char caractere;

    private float x;

    private float y;

    private float fontSize;

    private boolean bold;

    private boolean italic;

    private FonteDoEbook fonte;

}

So it suppose to get all these fonts I said and this foreach can get in this book I showed as example this font names:
CESPXI+NimbusSanL-Regu
JNISHD+MinionPro-It
ADEOBE+MinionPro-Bold
QFIOSQ+NimbusMonL-Regu
SHIDIU+MinionPro-Regular
F81
CESPXI+NimbusSanL-Regu

The font F81 specifically spam it on console something like that about 100 times:
05:48:46.158 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont -- No Unicode mapping for a99 (99) in font F81
05:48:46.160 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont -- No Unicode mapping for a108 (108) in font F81
05:48:46.160 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont -- No Unicode mapping for a97 (97) in font F81
05:48:46.160 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont -- No Unicode mapping for a115 (115) in font F81

Ebook opened in the browser
Ebook opened by my application
I already tried, instead of using the COS InputStream object, using new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes Here) but it didn't work either
I already write the bytes of one Font that I get from the PDFBox function in the foreach that I mentioned above into a ttf file and opened the file sucessfully in FontForge
I already tryed to set the font in Text object with this method:
if (texto.getFonte() != null && texto.getFonte().getInputStream() != null) {
    Font font = Font.loadFont(texto.getFonte().getInputStream(), texto.getFontSize());
    text.setStyle("-fx-font-family: " + texto.getFonte().getNome() + "; -fx-font-size: " + texto.getFontSize() + ";");

instead of:
if (texto.getFonte() != null && texto.getFonte().getInputStream() != null) {
    Font font = Font.loadFont(texto.getFonte().getInputStream(),texto.getFontSize());
    text.setFont(font);

but it didn't worked as well

@KJ actually the ternary function is a old code, now the else of ternary would never supposed to act.
I get the font InputStream through pdFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontFile().createInputStream(); to use in a JavaFx object to map and show de pdf file exactly as it is, so if I use a PDFont object or the object I created which is FonteDoEbook will work the same, in other words I need to get the bytes of the font with PDFBox library to JavaFx library, they not accept any common object

@KJ When the pdf file uses font that are not common, standard of the platform (windows, linux, mac) the font is embedded into pdf file, that is what I'm doing getting the InputStream of the fonts, retrieving these fonts.
I dont understand what did you said very well

@KJ the font names are the names of fonts obtained through the foreach I showed on the code separately, in which I use 'PDFont pdFont = resources.getFont(font);' to get the font data, I get these names when I printed on console, but I removed the sysout, that's why you can't see

@KJ this if: 'if (texto.getFonte() != null && texto.getFonte().getInputStream() != null) {', the logic is that: if the letter of the pdf have a non default font which is represented by getInputStream() != null, so get the inputstream and load the font so I can apply the font style to the letter, else if inputstream == null so it's a default font platform, then you load the font by the given name because you already have this font because it is a default font.
Like I said, the ternary function is a old code "Arial" would be never suppose to be used

@KJ It's a font problem, it's mapping in the right position (x,y) but because isn't loading the font correctly seems its not in right position, I don't know where is the misstake, it suppose to work
